# Nil polynomial quotient ring

Tags: commutative-algebra

Is the ring $R$ described in this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1966356/zero-dimensional-ring-without-idempotent-or-nilpotent-ideals?noredirect=1#comment4042140_1966356) a nil ring?

It seems to me that any polynomial $f\in R$ of zero constant term  is nilpotent, considering the greatest power $k$ of some $X_i$ existing in it, i.e., $f^k=0$. Thanks for any suggestion!

Comment: What do you call a nil ring?

Comment: @karparvar Can be a unitary ring nilpotent? And what about the other units (which are the constant polynomials in this case)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can't be a nil ring since it has a unit element different from $0$ (it contains a field), but the ideal $(X_2,\dots,X_n,\dots)$ is a nilideal.